# ¿con relación 1 a N laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, relaciones

Buenas vengo a ustedes a pedirle un poco de ayuda sobre relaciones 1 a N en laravel tengo que relacionar mi tabla persona, comentarios la cual seria que 1 persona tiene muchos comentarios, esa seria la logica ahora nos pasamos al codigo tengo la creación de mi persona correctamente y me muestra en una vista index todas las personas creadas y en una vista show le muestro la informacion completa de cada persona ahora dentro de esa vista show persona tengo un boton que me redirecciona a mi vista crear cometario la cual al llegar a esa vista seria que me capture el id de mi persona seleccionada y me lo cargue junto con los datos del comentario para realizar la relación pero no puedo hacer el paso de capturar el id de la persona y enviarlo como parámetro a mi campo persona_id que tengo en mi tabla comentario

mi Modelo persona con su realción

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class persona extends Model
{
        public function comentarios()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\comentario');
    }
}
```

Mi Modelo Comentario con su relación

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class comentario extends Model
{
        public function personas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\persona');
    }
}
```

Mi controlador persona la cual cargo la persona a mi DB

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Persona;
use App\Comentario;

class PersonaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
          $personas = Persona::all();
       return view('persona.index', compact('personas'));
        // return view('persona.index');
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('persona.create');
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $persona = new Persona();
        $persona->name=$request->input('name');
        $persona->alias=$request->input('alias');
        $persona->save();
        return 'Salvado';
    }
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Persona $persona)
    {
        // $persona = new Persona::fiend($id);, compact('persona')
        //$persona = Persona::find();
        //return $persona;
       return view('persona.show', compact('persona'));
        //
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

mi Controlador comentario que como ven estoy intentado muchas formas pero no logro dar con la soluciòn a mi problema

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comentario;
use App\Persona;

class ComentarioController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Persona $persona)
    {
        // if ($request->ajax()) {
        //     // $empresas = $persona->empresas;
        //     return response()->json($persona->id, 200);
        // }
        $comentario = Comentario::with('persona.id')->get();
        return view('comentario.index', compact('comentario'));
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

        $persona = Persona::orderBy('name')->get();
        return view('comentario.create', compact('persona'));
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Persona $persona, Request $request)
    {
        $comentario = new Comentario();
        //$persona = App\Persona::find($id);
        $comentario->comentario = $request->input('comentario');
        $comentario->persona_id = $persona->id;
        $comentario->save();
        return 'Salvado';
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

y aca muestros mis vistas

Vista Index Pesona

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title','Index')

@section('content')

    @foreach($personas as $persona)
         <tr>
          <td>{{ $persona->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $persona->alias }}</td>
          <td>
          <a href="/persona/{{ $persona->id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Ver má...</a>    
          </td>
          </tr>
         @endforeach

@endsection
```

Vista Show Persona

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title','persona')

@section('content')

      <tr>
      <td>{{ $persona->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $persona->alias }}</td>
      <td>
      <a href="/comentario/create" class="btn btn-primary">Ver má...</a> // con esto me envie a mi vista crear comentario intente pasarle el $persona->id algo asi /comentario/create{{$persona->id}} pero no me fuciono 
      </td>
      </tr>

@endsection
```

mi archivo de rutas esta asi

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('persona','PersonaController');
Route::resource('comentario','ComentarioController');
// Route::post('persona/{persona}/comentario', 'ComentarioController@store'); no me funciono 
// Route::get('persona/{persona}/comentario', 'ComentarioController@index'); tampoco me funciono
```

bueno ese problema tengo aun sigo buscando la solucion a mi problema que tengo si me pudieran ayuda en esto se los agradeceria un monto

Comment: Publicá tu archivo de rutas. Si nunca vas a ver el listado de todos los comentarios, sino que siempre los vas a ver ligados a una persona, lo ideal sería que tu ruta de comentarios siempre incluya la persona: `personas/{persona}/comentarios`. En el modelo `comentario` (por cierto van en mayúscula las clases), el método debería ser `persona`, en singular.

Comment: ya agrege mi archivo de rutas y como ves intente hacer eso comentado pero no me funciono me salia pagina no encontrada

Answer (score 1):

**Rutas:**
Por convención las rutas van en plural.

```php
Route::resource('personas', 'PersonaController');
Route::resource('personas.comentarios', 'ComentarioController');
```

Si hacés un `php artisan route:list` vas a ver las rutas que está generando. Pero al usar un `.` en un `resource` Laravel crea automáticamente lo que corresponde. Ejemplo:

```
personas/{persona}/comentarios
personas/{persona}/comentarios/{comentario}
```

---

**Modelos:**
Están bien creados, pero los nombres de las clases van en mayúscula y el `belongsTo` en singular (pertenece a una *persona*). Por otro lado, en las relaciones podes usar directamente la clase en vez de un string. La ventaja es que, según el IDE que utilices, eso te permite acceder directamente a la clase al hacerle click.

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Persona extends Model
{
    public function comentarios()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comentario::class);
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comentario extends Model
{
    public function persona()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Persona::class);
    }
}
```

---

**Controladores:**
El controlador de Persona parecería estar bien.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Persona;
use App\Comentario;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ComentarioController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Trae los comentarios de UNA persona (no se si es lo que querés).
     * Cambio acá también los plurales.
     */
    public function index(Persona $persona)
    {
        $comentarios = $persona->comentarios;

        return view('comentarios.index', compact('comentarios'));
    }

    /**
     * Si en el formulario no vas a mostrar ninguna información de
     * la persona en cuestión, no hace falta que la pases en una
     * variable. Al estar en la URL sabemos de quien se trata.
     *
     * Del formulario sacamos el campo "persona_id", entiendo que
     * siempre vas a llegar al formulario de creación al hacer
     * click en "crear comentario" desde una persona.
     */
    public function create(Persona $persona)
    {
        return view('comentarios.create');
    }

    /**
     * El primer parámetro tiene que ser Request, no Persona.
     * En vez de guardar "persona_id", guardamos desde la relación.
     */
    public function store(Request $request, Persona $persona)
    {
        $comentario = new Comentario();
        $comentario->comentario = $request->input('comentario');
        $persona->comentarios()->save($comentario);

        return 'Salvado';
    }
}
```

---

**Vistas:**
No escribas a mano las URLs, usá `route()` aprovechando que cada ruta tiene un [nombre](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes). El parámetro que tenés que pasar es `$persona`, si no especificás un campo, Laravel usa automáticamente el ID, pero lo [podes modificar](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding). Justamente la ventaja de no especificar el ID en la URL, es que si el día de mañana lo cambiás por otra cosa, no tenés que corregir las vistas.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Index')

@section('content')

    @foreach($personas as $persona)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $persona->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $persona->alias }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('personas.show', $persona) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Ver má...</a>    
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach

@endsection
```

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title','persona')

@section('content')

    <tr>
        <td>{{ $persona->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $persona->alias }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route('personas.comentarios.create', $persona) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Ver má...</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

@endsection
```

---

**RouteServiceProvider:**
Entiendo que no debería hacer falta, pero si ves que desde los controladores no se resuelve `$persona` de manera correcta, vas a tener que hacer un [explicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding).

En el archivo `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('persona', \App\Persona::class);
}
```

---

Ésto debería ser suficiente para orientarte. Te dejo para que pienses la lógica de `edit/update`.